# How to find out if an Ada file was compiled using static or dynamic elaboration

Tags: ada, gnat

I am having some issues with detected elaboration circularities. I am almost sure that all the sources were compiled with -gnatE.

To further investigate this I would like to check in the ada lib directory if a file was compiled with static or dynamic elaboration.

Does there exist a command with which you can retrieve this info? I am using FSF-GNAT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Along with the compiled files (.o) there are ALI files (.ali) which are text files with many details about the compilation that has happened.
The first bunch of information is about compiler switches.

Comment: Addendum to answer (related info): [GNAT UG 3.7](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/the_gnat_compilation_model.html#the-ada-library-information-files) and [`Lib.Writ`](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/ada/lib-writ.ads?revision=273107&view=markup#l89) for descriptions of the ALI file content.

Comment: For a quick check, it’s lines beginning `A`: if you find `A -gnatE`, then dynamic elaboration, if not, then static.